# DropDownList Selection instead of a TextBox in AutoGenerated Gridview Columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I bind a Gridview read from my Oracle Database. I have an edit, and delete button. My aim is that when I have a certain table selected and I press my edit button, I replace the first two textboxes with dropdownlists so I restrict what the user can pick in order to run my SQL statement to my database with the selectedvalue in the dropdownlist instead of the textbox value. I have no TemplateFields to reference my columns in the Gridview because they are autogenerated. When I press my update button on my Gridview, it doesn't update from the DropDownList selected value but instead the text value which was in the Gridview. This is a snippet of my code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
                {
                     //Locate the textboxs I want to replace
                    TextBox disableJOBRun = e.Row.Cells[2].Controls[0] as TextBox;

                    TextBox disableAction = e.Row.Cells[3].Controls[0] as TextBox;
                   //Create the new DropDownLists
                    DropDownList JobRunSelection = new DropDownList();

                    DropDownList ActionSelection = new DropDownList();
                    //Bind the DropDownLists

                   JobRunSelection.DataSource = ds;
                   JobRunSelection.DataValueField = "JOBNAME";
                   JobRunSelection.DataBind();

                    ActionSelection.DataSource = dsTwo;
                    ActionSelection.DataValueField = "NAME";
                    ActionSelection.DataBind();
                    con.Close();

                     //Change Text of Textbox 
                    JobRunSelection.SelectedValue = disableJOBRun.Text;

                    ActionSelection.SelectedValue = disableAction.Text;

                    //Add the DropdownsLists to the Gridview
                    e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(JobRunSelection);

                    e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(ActionSelection);


                    JobRunSelection.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

                    ActionSelection.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");


                    JobRunSelection.ID = "DropDownJobRunSelection";

                    ActionSelection.ID = "DropDownActionSelection";
                    //Hide Textboxes
                    disableJOBRun.Visible = false;
                    disableAction.Visible = false;
                  }
}  
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)

        //Get Connection to database
        GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        String newJobID = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[2].Controls[0])).Text;
        String newAction = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;
        //Update Table
        cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE " + SelectedTable + " SET JOBID = :param2,   WHERE " + KeyName + " = " + "'" + KeyValue + "'";
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":param2", newJobID);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(":param3", newAction);
```

Perhaps Page_Load resets the text back to its original? If so, how would I go about implementing my DropDownLists? Thanks for any help and I will post any more code necessary.

Comment: Use a template field.

Comment: How are you binding data to the GridView? Are you using an `IsPostBack` check?

Comment: @VDWWD I load my read data from the database and load it into a Datatable which I bind to my Gridview. I am currently not using a IsPostBack check with my BindGrid method.

Comment: Start using one. If not the updates values will be overwritten by the old ones.

Comment: @wazz I'm not sure how I would use a template field since my Gridview is autogenerated and the data from my tables determine the Gridview specs

Comment: @VDWWD However, I am running the Update statement to my database then Rebinding the Gridview by reading from the database again. I don't believe I need a _IsPostBack_ check?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, I had switched the order of the variables of the Dropdownlist selected value and the text box text. Once I switched them, my text boxes changed their values.